# NSMutableArray addObject not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have declared an `NSMutableArray *categories` in my view controller .h file, and declared a property for it.

In the `parser:foundCharacters:` method of the `NSXMLParser` delegate in my .m file, I have this code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string  
{  
    if (elementFound)  
    {  
        element = string;  
        [self.categories addObject:element];  
    }  
}
```

But when I hover over the `[self.categories addObject:element]` line after stepping into it in debug mode, XCode tells me the size is 0x0, 0 objects. There are 3 elements in my XML file so 3 items should be in the array.

I'm missing something really obvious and I can't figure out what.

Comment: For your future posting: the way to format code is to select the code block, and indent everything 4 spaces by using the "code" formatter button at the top of the post editor.

Comment: sorry - i copied and pasted from another forum, guess the formatting didnt hold up to much! thanks

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The "0x0" part is a memory address. Specifically, "nil", which means your mutable array doesn't exist at the time this is being called. Try creating it in your -init method:

```
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Don't forget to release it in your -dealloc.

Comment: I don't know why I keep forgetting to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: (2012 Update: If you're using ARC, the release/dealloc part can be ignored.)

Comment: Thank you! It's easy to keep forgetting that messages to nil object references don't fail in Objective-C.

Comment: Come from Swift, I keep forgetting to `new` NSMutable array too:) In Swift we usually initialize the array when declare it or give it an optional mark. While in Objective-C, apparently it works differently. And compiler will not warn yout about that in OC.

Answer (score 8):

Initialize an empty array using

```
categories = [NSMutableArray array];
```

The array class method are autoreleased so no need to release.

Comment: Vishu - Your solution is working, but I think Joshua Nozzi's solution is better since it needs less memory.

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to my answer five and a half years ealier, just using the convenience method instead of alloc/init. There is no difference in memory usage and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi The array class method by itself produces an autoreleased array, meaning you don't have to (and should not) release it manually.

Comment: I’m aware of that. My point is that you added a functionally-equivalent answer six years later, well after manual reference counting was no longer a concern to begin with due to ARC. Why not answer a question that hasn’t already been answered or answer one with a demonstrably better answer?