# Add objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to add objects to NSMutableArray (categoriasArray), but its not done by the iterator:

```
@synthesize categoriasArray;

for (int i = 0; i < [categories count]; i++) {

        categoria *cat = [[categoria alloc] initWithDictionary:[categories objectAtIndex:i]]; 
        [self.categoriasArray addObject:cat]; 
        cat=nil;

    }
```

After the for iterator, categoriasArray has 0 objects.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you initialize `categoriasArray`?

Comment: categoriasArray is nil -- you never created it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that the array is not `nil` before the loop starts:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.categoriasArray); // This will output null

for (int i = 0; i < [categories count]; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

What you should understand is that synthesizing the property `categoriasArray` doesn't initialize it, it just generates the setter and the getter methods. So, to solve your problem, initialize the array before the loop, (or in the init method of your class):

```
self.categoriasArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

---

The other possibility is that `categories` is itself `nil` or doesn't contain any items. To check that, add `NSLog`s before the loop:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.categoriasArray); 
NSLog(@"%@", categories); 
NSLog(@"%d", [categories count]); 

for (int i = 0; i < [categories count]; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ssh, it was the NSMutableArray,it was not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
     for(categoria *cat in categoria){

        [self.categoriasArray addObject:cat];
        // check you go here or not
    }
```

Comment: @sch it is fast enumeration. you not need to count the array

Answer (score 0):

I would advise getting in the habit of initializing your arrays with autorelease formatting such as the following.This is not only less to type but also good practice for mem management purposes. Of course if you are using ARC then both will work. This goes the same for NSString and many others **(i.e. self.categoriasString = [NSMutableString string];)**

```
self.categoriasArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Afterword you can add objects to that array by calling `[self.categoriasArray addObject:cat];`