# Why won't my NSMutableArray change its value when changed in an if statement in Objective - C?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, boolean

I'm trying to create a NSMutableArray within a function that continuously runs, and initialize its values just once so that it doesn't keep initializing the values (thus replacing the changed values) as the function is repetitively called. My problem is when I try to initialize the values in an if statement the values in the array won't change, it keeps printing "value is 0" when I'm expecting it to be printing "value is 1"

Here's my relevant code:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * shapeMarked;
 @synthesize shapeMarked;

 //locationManager is the function that's continuously called

 -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
 {

 //event count is an integer that continuously increases by one each time the 
 //parent function is called, this if statement is used so that it only happens 
 //once

 if(eventcount == 1){

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        BOOL b = YES;

        [shapeMarked addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:b]];

        NSLog(@"value is %d", [[shapeMarked objectAtIndex:i] boolValue] );

    }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Is `eventcount == 1` ever matched? Add a NSLog in that if-case. Also, is shapeMarked actually a valid NSArray? Add a `NSLog(@"array: %@", shapeMarked);`

Comment: When I  added the NSLog(@"array ... ); it's outputting "array: (null). I know that "event count == 1" is matched because NSLog outputs, if it wasn't matched I wouldn't get the output because NSLog is called within the if statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Alloc and init the array somewhere! Did you?

```
self.shapeMarked = [NSMutableArray array];
```

eg in your init method should do. Without it, your shapeMarked is just nil.

Comment: Is there a way I can do that outside of any functions after the "@property" or "@synthesize" because when I try to do that on the "@property" line it gives me errors.

Comment: You need to go and read the basic Objective-C guide;  understand methods and classes, designated initializers and the like.... then the answer will be obvious (and you'll have a foundation for success).

Comment: As I wrote, try your init method. Also release the object in dealloc. Bbum's advice is sure a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Your array obviously is not a valid `NSMutableArray` instance - or in other words, it is just `nil`.

That is the problem of your code.

When invoking a selector on a `nil` object, the return value always is `nil` (for objects) or `0` (for scalar types). Invoking `objectAtIndex:` will result into a returned `nil`. You are expecting a `NSNumber` instance and as said before, that will be `nil`. Now you are invoking `boolValue` on that `nil` instance and that will return `0` as you are expecting a scalar data type. See Apple's excellent [Objective-C documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7).

You most likely have forgotten to initialize `shapeMarked` with a valid `NSMutableArray` instance.