# Image from UIImagePicker to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Very simply, I want to take a photo using `UIImagePicker` and place it into an `NSMutableArray`. I hve the following code below. The camera part works fine and for test purposes the image is displayed in a `UIImage` called *photoImageView*. However I can't seem to add the image into the array. Any help gratefully received.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *photos;

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage *photoTaken = (UIImage *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
photoImageView.image=photoTaken;
[photos addObject:[UIImage photoTaken];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? `[UIImage photoTaken]` would not even compile ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working) - #1 in the [nsmutablearray] category.

Comment: did you have allocate photos array like  photos=[NSMutableArray new]; else what is your output when NSLog the photos array.

Comment: @MartinR you are correct it does not compile as is. I have tried so many combinations without joy - hence asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Are you initialising the photos NSMutableArray? Sometimes addObject: won't throw an error when trying to insert an object into a NULL NSArray.

2)

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *photoTaken = (UIImage *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if (photoTaken)
    {
        photoImageView.image=photoTaken;
        [photos addObject:photoTaken];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Selected photo is NULL");
    }
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you instantiated the array somewhere (`viewDidLoad` for example):

```
self.photos = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Modify below after adding to (Ian L )

```
     [photos addObject: photoTaken];
```

Answer (score 1):

`photoTaken` is already instantiated as an `UIImage` object. No need to do :

```
[photos addObject : [UIImage photoTaken]];
```

Simply do this :

```
[photos addObject : photoTaken];
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark this as the answer that solved your question.