# Trying to add a NSMutableDictionary to variable with a block parameter but after addObject always returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to add a NSMutableDictionary to _ons variable with a block parameter but after addObject always returns null.

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableArray * ons;

--------------------------------------------------------------------

NSMutableDictionary *on = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[on setObject:eventName forKey:@"eventName"];
[on setObject:[callback copy] forKey:@"callback"]; // callback it's a block

[_ons addObject:on];
NSLog(@"_ons: %@", _ons); // always prints null!!!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never instantiating `_ons`. Somewhere in your code, you need to call:

```
self.ons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

(In case you’re new to Objective-C, your code wasn’t crashing because messages to `nil` are no-ops that return 0, instead of crashing like in some other languages.)